# How to get the length of a nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, string-length

Hi i have nested array how do i get the length of the nested array? It needs to show

Comment: You need that `length` in your html or JS?

Comment: its a switcher based on the ng-show

Comment: Can u tell us what problem you are currently facing. Because the above code seems to be fine

Comment: try `movie.meta.actors.length === 1` and `movie.meta.actors.length !== 1`

Comment: Can you please provide the Controller code also? Are you sure the `movie.meta.actors` is an array?

Comment: i think that div need to be outside the ng-repeat

Comment: try `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`

Comment: Although it's not related to your problem, i recommand using [ngPluralize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPluralize) for this kind of stuff.

Comment: Vanojx1 yes i tried to move it outside but did not work as well

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="movie in movies">
  <div ng-repeat="actor in movie.meta.actors" > 
    <div ng-if="movie.meta.actors.length ==1"> Actor: <div>
    <div ng-if="movie.meta.actors.length !=1"> Actors: <div>
    <text>{{actor.name}}<text>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: same result not working, it does not show any information

Comment: Please provide your controller code. I need to check the value of `$scope.movies`

Comment: i added the controller and a temp link to the scope.movies

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ng-switch

```
<div ng-repeat="movie in movies" ng-switch="movie.meta.actors.length > 1">
  <div ng-repeat="actor in movie.meta.actors"> 
     <div ng-switch-when="true"> Actors: <div>
     <div ng-switch-default> Actor: <div>
     <text>{{actor.name}}<text>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/n3ekmpn6/

Comment: As soon as i add it like above it NG-Repeat is not working anymore

Comment: @EwaldBos check my jsfiddle above

Comment: i can't seem to get to work i will add a part of the json